# newMember.guild.channels.cache.find not working in my discord bot's code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a Discord bot for a friend. The purpose of the bot would be to add a role to any member of a specific voice channel and remove it when they leave the channel. Here is the code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // définition des constantes
  const testChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === ' 1h de travail');
  const role = newMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'test');

  // détection
  if (newMember.channelID === testChannel.id) {
    // Triggered when the user joined the channel we tested for
    if (!newMember.member.roles.cache.has(role)) 
      newMember.member.roles.add(role);
      // Add the role to the user if they don't already have it
    }
    else if (oldMember.member.roles.cache.has(role)) 
      oldMember.member.roles.remove(role);
  }
});
```

When I launch the bot using `npm run dev` and then join a voice channel, I get this error:

```
/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/index.js:13
    const testChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === ' 1h de travail');
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/index.js:13:56)
    at Client.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at VoiceStateUpdateHandler.handle (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/VoiceStateUpdate.js:40:16)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/archie/Documents/my-bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:379:20)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't understand it and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: looks like your using discord v11 >= can you just double check it's up to date

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using discord.js v11 with code written for v12. In the older version, `guild.channels` was a Collection, not a Manager so it doesn't have a `cache` property. That's why it's `undefined` and that's why you can't use `.find` on it.

All you need to do is update your discord.js to the latest version.

PS: If you're using discord.js v12, the `client.voiceStateUpdate` event returns `oldState` and `newState` instead of `oldMember`, and `newMember`. So, it returns the `VoiceState` of the member before and after the update, not the member itself.