# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') mirano

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

can you help me , i have a probleme with my discord bot , i have a welcome message on a specific channel and all work , message are send but after the bot crash with this error :

[image]

`

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
      console.log('User @' + member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');

      const welcomepublic = new client.discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(client.config.mainColor)
        .setAuthor({
          name: client.config.botName,
          iconURL: client.user.avatarURL()
        })
        .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())
        .setDescription(client.locales.other.joinPublicMessage.replace('USERNAME', '<@' + member.user.id + '>').replace('SERVERNAME', client.config.serverName))
        .setFooter({
          text: "Dev by Akaya",
          iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/PNK8rlZ.png"
        });
      member.guild.channels.cache.get(client.config.welcomeChannel).send({
        embeds: [welcomepublic]
      })
      var role = client.config.roleJoin
      member.roles.add(role);
    });
```

`

i dont understand because sometime the bot work and sometime the bot crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it exactly tells you what the issue is, the `member.guild.channels.cache.get(client.config.welcomeChannel)` is `undefined`. I would suggest checking if the value exists before trying to use the send method, i.e.

```
const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(client.config.welcomeChannel);
if (welcomeChannel) {
  welcomeChannel.send({
    embeds: [welcomepublic]
  })
}
```

Comment: oki , but is a global value in a config files , she can't be undefined , that what i dont understand

Comment: It seems that you are getting it from the cache, maybe it sometimes is not present in the cache. Are there other options to get the channel, without the cache part?

Comment: Also check out this reponse https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909467/2746366

Comment: ok i go check this